# Как строить веб-странички без погружения во фронтенд?

Tags: javascript, html, css, python, frontend

Ищу простой способ генерировать квадратные веб странички без погружения в html и css и с минимальным погружением в js(хочется ajax)
для визуализации графиков, таблиц и карт с кнопочками, галочками и ползунками.

Бэкенд на питоне. Хочется максимум функциональных компонентов, автоматическая генерация всего фронта и что б это выглядело чистенько, без серьезных багов. Желательно с визуальным редактором (если такие есть)

Из того, что нашел, есть такие штуки:

- Виджеты для Jupyter, позволяющие с использованием лишь python добавлять различные компоненты, но существующие только внутри ноутбуков, что совсем не подходит
- Фреймворки Bokeh и Dash. Dash или публичный или платный, что не очень удобдно. Bokeh на первый взгляд подходит, но для интерактивности придется делать вставки из js кода и полностью разбираться в архитектуре фронтенда, чего я пытаюсь избежать - тогда ведь проще не использовать питон для генерации фронта вообще, а сразу вникать в js и html

Comment: Если хочется красивого веба без погружения в JS и CSS - возьмите готовый CSS фреймворк - лучше начать с bootstrap - https://getbootstrap.com - там и красивые стили и готовые JS модули для большинства задач типа слайды картинок, аккордеоны и прочее. Всё что нужно будет знать это базовый HTML - а там потом дергаете куски примеров из мануала и вставляете в свой питоновский код шаблонов.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве фронта можно взять **[Material UI](https://material-ui.com/)**. Достаточно много готовых компонентов и решений. Много усилий не нужно, только если делать что-то кастомное придется повозиться.

Графики, тут бы посоветовал **[D3.js](https://d3js.org/)**, очень крутая штука, если вы желаете работать с данными, а так же визуализировать их.

Comment: Автор скорее всего подразумевает конструкторы страницы аля Qt Creator или Delphi.